# How to read GET request from client C

Tags: c, network-programming, httprequest

My program establishes an HTTP server. After calling `listen()` and `accept()`, how do I read a GET request like this:

```
GET /path HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n
```

Comment: Hint: What does `accept()` return? What function(s) work on the returned value?

Comment: Ummm call the `recv()` function?  Ok, in all seriousness, check out [Beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) to socket programming.  And you may want to read the [HTTP RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616), because an HTTP request can have additional headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using blocking socket, first you need to know if data is available to read. That you can do using **select** api. 
Next accept returns one socket FD to you. Using that socket FD you can receive data.

***Accept code example***

```
struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
int addr_len;
int new_fd;

addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
new_fd =  accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,(socklen_t *)&addr_len);
```

***Select and read example***

```
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 0;
timeout.tv_usec = 100;
ret_value = select(max_fd + 1, READ_FD_SETS, NULL , NULL , &timeout);

if ((ret_value <= 0) && (errno!=EINTR))
{
  //error
}
else
{
   //read data now
   rc = recv(new_fd, buffer, buffer length, 0)
}
```

Note: If you want better performance you may like R&D on epoll sockets.

Comment: Note: if this is just a simple educational thing, and you're only handling one socket at a time, you don't need `select`.

Comment: Doing this `int addr_len; ... accept(..., (socklen_t *)&addr_len)`is a bad idea. You should define `socklen_t addr_len;` instead and drop the cast.